# Uclinux vs Linux

Tags: microcontroller, linux, cortex-m4, os

Searching Internet, I found an operating system called uclinux which can run on ARM Cortex-M7.
How is it different from the orginal Linux which runs on PC??
What about librarys such as QT GUI? Is it possible to run GUI programs base on QT on uclinux??
(Please answer more specifically about stm32f746g discovery board)

Comment: Search the Internet again, please !

Comment: I have searched Internet alot but I could not find technical information.

Comment: Look at it's [homepage](http://www.uclinux.org/).

Answer (score 3):

As answered by its homepage, or its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CClinux):

> μClinux is a variation of the Linux kernel, previously maintained as a fork, that targets microcontrollers without a memory management unit (MMU).

There is no difference at this point. It's just a layer that handled memory management for a device that did not have it, particularly micro controllers.

QT will work with uclinux, just google `uclinux QT` or `stm32f746g qt` for various examples.

Comment: I read about MMU. But is it the only difference between uclinux and Linux??

Comment: What about QT? Does it run on uclinux or it runs on bate metal?

Comment: You should understand that there are ramifications to running without an MMU. For example, launching a program will be slower due to final relocation having to be done at that time instead of at link time. Also, multiple processes running the same executable will take more memory due to not being able to share copy-on-write pages. Finally, there is no protection from crashing the OS due to an errant memory write.

Comment: By difference, I do not mean any side effect caused by MMU. I mean do we have user and kernel mode? Am I able to use the same systemcalls?? Can I write device drivers just like the linux one?? And things like this...